# Dropdown list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

How does one create a dropdown list only using JS?
Example I have my HTML, I know for dropdown list in HTML you use select and option tags but if I were not to change any HTML elements and only use Javascript and link the html in it to create a Day-Month-Year dropdown using JS, how would that be done?

My HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Testing for JS Dropdown</title>
  <style>
    div {
      width: 50%;
      margin: auto;
      height: 200px;
      border: 5px solid black;
      background-color: silver;
    }
    .field {
      padding-left: 10px;
      width: 60px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    h2 { padding-left: 10px;}
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="prototype.js"></script>
  <script src="JStester.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <h2> Select Day-Month-Year </h2>
    <p> <span class="field">Day </span><select id="days"> </select></p>
    <p> <span class="field">Month</span><select id="months"> </select></p>
    <p> <span class="field">Year</span><select id="years"></select></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you use JQuery ? -I mean, you should.

Comment: u can create an array and loop through all the data and inject the data inside ur html. its pretty easy just search over net

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
  var qntYears = 4;
  var selectYear = $("#years");
  var selectMonth = $("#months");
  var selectDay = $("#days");
  var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  
  for (var y = 0; y < qntYears; y++){
    let date = new Date(currentYear);
    var yearElem = document.createElement("option");
    yearElem.value = currentYear 
    yearElem.textContent = currentYear;
    selectYear.append(yearElem);
    currentYear--;
  } 

  for (var m = 0; m < 12; m++){
      let monthNum = new Date(2018, m).getMonth()
      let month = monthNames[monthNum];
      var monthElem = document.createElement("option");
      monthElem.value = monthNum; 
      monthElem.textContent = month;
      selectMonth.append(monthElem);
    }

    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var day = d.getDate();

    selectYear.val(year); 
    selectYear.on("change", AdjustDays);  
    selectMonth.val(month);    
    selectMonth.on("change", AdjustDays);

    AdjustDays();
    selectDay.val(day)
    
    function AdjustDays(){
      var year = selectYear.val();
      var month = parseInt(selectMonth.val()) + 1;
      selectDay.empty();
      
      //get the last day, so the number of days in that month
      var days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate(); 
      
      //lets create the days of that month
      for (var d = 1; d <= days; d++){
        var dayElem = document.createElement("option");
        dayElem.value = d; 
        dayElem.textContent = d;
        selectDay.append(dayElem);
      }
    }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Testing for JS Dropdown</title>
  <style>
    div {
      width: 50%;
      margin: auto;
      height: 200px;
      border: 5px solid black;
      background-color: silver;
    }
    .field {
      padding-left: 10px;
      width: 60px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    h2 { padding-left: 10px;}
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="prototype.js"></script>
  <script src="JStester.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <h2> Select Day-Month-Year </h2>
    <p> <span class="field">Day </span><select id="days"> </select></p>
    <p> <span class="field">Month</span><select id="months"> </select></p>
    <p> <span class="field">Year</span><select id="years"></select></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this by using only JAVASCRIPT

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Testing for JS Dropdown</title>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
var dt_obj= new Date();
function addOption(selectbox,text,value )
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = text;
optn.value = value;
selectbox.options.add(optn);
}
///////////// date //////////////////
var today_date= dt_obj.getDate();

function addOption_list1(){
var month = dt_obj.getMonth();
month = month + 1;

if(month == "1" || month == "3" || month == "5" ||
  month == "7" || month == "8" || month == "10" || month == "12"){
  for (var i=1; i < 32;++i){
addOption(document.drop_list.days, i, i);
if(i== today_date){document.drop_list.days.options[i].selected=true;}
}
  }
  else if ( month == "2"){
  for (var i=1; i < 29;++i){
addOption(document.drop_list.days, i, i);
if(i== today_date){document.drop_list.days.options[i].selected=true;}
}
  }
  else{
  for (var i=1; i < 31;++i){
addOption(document.drop_list.days, i, i);
if(i== today_date){document.drop_list.days.options[i].selected=true;}
}
  }

addOption_list2();
}
//////////////End of Date //////////


///////////// Month //////////////////
var current_month=dt_obj.getMonth() +1;
function addOption_list2(){
var month = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
for (var i=0; i < month.length;++i){
addOption(document.drop_list.months, month[i], month[i]);
if(i== current_month){document.drop_list.months.options[i].selected=true;}
}
addOption_list3();

}
//////////////End of Month //////////


///////////// Year //////////////////
var current_year=dt_obj.getFullYear();
function addOption_list3(){
for (var i=0; i < 7;++i){
var j=current_year+i-2;
match_year=current_year+i;
addOption(document.drop_list.years, j, j);
if((j-1)== current_year ){document.drop_list.years.options[i].selected=true;}
}

}
//////////////End of Year //////////

function monthChange(){
 var month = document.getElementById("months").value;
  document.getElementById("days").value ="";
  if(month == "January" || month == "March" || month == "May" ||
  month == "July" || month == "August" || month == "October" || month == "December"){
  for (var i=1; i < 32;++i){
addOption(document.drop_list.days, i, i);
if(i== today_date){document.drop_list.days.options[i].selected=true;}
}
  }
  else if ( month == "February"){
  for (var i=1; i < 29;++i){
addOption(document.drop_list.days, i, i);
if(i== today_date){document.drop_list.days.options[i].selected=true;}
}
  }
  else{
  for (var i=1; i < 31;++i){
addOption(document.drop_list.days, i, i);
if(i== today_date){document.drop_list.days.options[i].selected=true;}
}
  }
  
}

</script>
  <style>
    div {
      width: 50%;
      margin: auto;
      height: 200px;
      border: 5px solid black;
      background-color: silver;
    }
    .field {
      padding-left: 10px;
      width: 60px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    h2 { padding-left: 10px;}
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="prototype.js"></script>
  <script src="JStester.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload=addOption_list1();>
<form name="drop_list">
 <div>
    <h2> Select Day-Month-Year </h2>
    <p> <span class="field">Day </span><select id="days" name="days"> 
    <option value="" >Date</option></select></p>
    <p> <span class="field">Month</span><select id="months" name="months" onchange="monthChange()">
    <option value="" >Month</option></select></p>
    <p> <span class="field">Year</span><select name="years">
      <option value="" >Year</option>
    </select></p>
  </div>
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```